# Terminology: order vs. degree (in general)

Tags: terminology

The word *[degree](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=degree&searchmode=none)* comes from Latin `degradus` (through French), which means something like step down.

The word *[order](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=order&searchmode=none)* comes from Latin `ordinem` (through French too), which means row,rank.

Is there a reason why orders are called orders in maths and degrees, degrees? For example, is there fundamental reasons why the number of derivatives in an ODE is called order and not degree, and the degree of a polynomial degree and not order?

Comment: This terminology is pretty mixed up in mathematics, its usage is perhaps less consistent than you might imagine. For instance, the number $n$ is called the degree of the polynomial $P(z)=(z-a)^n$ and it is also called the order of the zero $z=a$ of $P(z)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher That's precisely because I can't see fundamental reason to this terminology that I am asking if there is any :-) The answer might very well be no!

Comment: Etymology often has very little to do with meaning, especially in mathematics.  You may find it helpful to look up "order" at http://jeff560.tripod.com/o.html,

Comment: @RobertIsrael Very interesting, thank you. This tend to confirm there is no reason other than historical ones.

Comment: Analytic functions have zeros with orders, polynomials have roots with multiplicities.  The meaning is essentially the same (at least if you're working in the field $\mathbb C$).